# Postgresql. Выбор из поля createdAt с фильтром только по часам и минутам

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Здравствуйте! В таблице есть поле "createdAt" (TIMESTAMP), которое равно времени создания поля.

```
id| createdAt
------------------------------
1 | 2016-07-01 17:46:01.026000
2 | 2016-07-22 09:11:38.386000
3 | 2016-07-01 16:52:12.026000
```

Как выбрать поля, в которых createdAt есть "17:46" например? "LIKE" не срабатывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where extract(hour from createdAt) = 17 
    and extract(minute from createdAt) = 46
```

Или

```
where date_trunc('minute', createdAt::time) = '17:46:00'
```

По второму выражению при необходимости удобнее индекс строить. Но можно и для первого выкрутиться.